# Finding a sequences upper and lower bounds

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a series defined as $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+2)}+...+ \frac{1}{(2n)}$ for $n\geq1$.

How can I show that $a_n\leq\frac{n}{(n+1)}$ and that it is also bounded?

So far I have tried to work out the first few terms like $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$ ,  $a_2=\frac{7}{12}$,  $a_3=\frac{37}{60}$,  $a_4=\frac{533}{840}$ so I can see it is increasing but cannot see to show the above algebraically!

I know there is a question similar but I am not working out whether it converges or not

Comment: You have a sum of $n$ terms, and each term is $\le \frac{1}{n+1}$, so ...

Comment: I see, but it there a way of working it out rather than using intuition

Comment: That is working it out, that isn't intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is increasing because, for each $n>1$,\begin{align}a_n-a_{n-1}&=\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1n\\&=\frac1{2n(2n-1)}\\&>0.\end{align}And it is bounded because, for each natural $n$,\begin{align}0&<a_n\\&=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}\\&\leqslant\overbrace{\frac1{n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{n+1}}^{n\text{ times}}\\&=\frac n{n+1}\\&<1.\end{align}